# AngularJs and Dynamic controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on some page, with different tabs used as panels... 
I was running in some issues, and didn't worked it out yet. 
I decided now to split all my logic in multiple controllers, but 
then I need to fix this issue : if I put a fixed controller in my code like ng-controller="MediaImageController", my tabs are working well, and multiple controllers are instantiated. Now I added some property to make the controller dynamic and I get this error :

Argument 'workspace.controller' is not a function, got string

So yes it's a string ! but it's working fine without binding. 
So do I have to instantiate the controller first ? and how can I do this ?

My controller looks like this :

```
function MediaImageControllerView($scope, $stateParams, MediaImageService) {}
```

and Angular App definition is

```
app.service('MediaImageService', MediaImageService);
app.controller('MediaImageHome', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'MediaImageService', MediaImageHome]);
app.controller('MediaImageControllerView', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'MediaImageService', MediaImageControllerView]);
app.controller('MediaImageEditController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'MediaImageService', MediaImageEditController]);
app.controller('MediaImageFolderNewController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'MediaImageService', MediaImageFolderNewController]);
```

The HTML code here

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <tabset vertical="false" type="tabs">
        <tab ng-repeat="workspace in workspaces"
             heading="{{workspace.name}}"
             active="workspace.active" disabled="workspace.disabled">
            <div ng-controller="workspace.controller" ng-include="workspace.url">
            </div>
        </tab>
    </tabset>
</div>
```

The main controller code :

```
function MediaImageHome($scope, $stateParams, MediaImageService) {
    $scope.$on('workspaceDisableAll', function () {
        angular.forEach($scope.workspaces, function (workspace) {
            workspace.disabled = true;
        });
    });

    $scope.$on('removeLastTab', function () {
        $scope.workspaces.splice($scope.workspaces.length - 1, 1);
        if ($scope.workspaces.length > 0) {
            $scope.workspaces[$scope.workspaces.length - 1].disabled = false;
        }
    });

    $scope.$on('workSpaceAdd', function (childController, controller, name, url) {
        $scope.$emit('workspaceDisableAll');
        var id = $scope.workspaces.length + 1;
        $scope.workspaces.push({
            url: url,
            controller: controller,
            id: id,
            name: name,
            active: true,
            disabled: false
        });
    });

    $scope.workspaces = [
    {
        name: "Home",
        active: true,
        disabled: false,
        url: '/Media/MediaImage/GetTemplateList',
        controller: 'MediaImageControllerView'
    }];

};
```

Comment: what you are trying to do there won't work, because angular has to parse the expression to get the name of the controller, but the parser won't run until after the controller is initialized.

Comment: so what is the solution ? I saw different working samples, but they are using simple functions and not controllers... I guess that if I fix the controller in the loaded Template that will fix my problem ? ... Could have thought about this first :=)))

Comment: And indeed that's working... that will make my day... till I find a better way :=)